# How can I send same email multiple times in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, email, mobile-mail

I wanted to send a single email to different users. I save an email to drafts and send the email to a user and it goes to the sent box instead of staying in the drafts box. Is there a way I can send an email repeatedly from the drafts box?

Comment: Why not put several peoplke in the To box - iOS will send that email to each of them

Comment: In addition to what @Mark suggests and to the answers, you can also just put all the email addresses in the BCC field. This hides them so none of the recipients can see who else the email was sent to.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A good way to achieve this using just the builtin apps on iOS is to save your email as a Note in the **Notes** app. You can then **Share it by Mail**, and it will be formatted for you automatically, with the first line becoming the subject of your email.

You could even setup a Notes folder with a whole set of email templates that way.

Your question pertains to iOS and iPad, but in macOS you may also select a previously sent email, then go into the menu bar and click **Message** → **Send Again** or **Redirect**. These commands are also available through right-click.

Of course the **Notes** solution still applies in macOS.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the ["Mail Aide"](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/mail-aide/id1180678139?ls=1&mt=8) app from the apple store,which was easy for saving the draft and sending the same mail multiple times.But theres was some downside with how the attachments are made available for the mail(the old traditional way of long pressing the attachment).

Comment: Will go with you.Just used the app.looks simple and solves the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Sending a message will automatically move it out of your drafts. However, you can use the 'Send again' or 'Forward' options on messages in the 'sent' folder, to send the same message again.