# Quickly send pre-written response on Mac mail?

Tags: mail.app

I get a lot of emails from recruiters sending irrelevant jobs to me, so I have a standard response that I copy and paste into replies. At the moment I do this manually from a saved text file. Is there a quicker way of doing this?

I was imagining there would be some way to save a reply so 1 button or shortcut would send this reply.

Comment: Answers for Mac Mail may differ from answers for iOS Mail, don't see how this qualifies as a duplicate

Comment: Related https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/277818/how-can-i-send-same-email-multiple-times-in-ios?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Quickly insert a standard response on macOS

**Prepare your response**

1. Open TextEdit.
2. Create new empty document (CMD+N).
3. Type your desired response.
4. Select the text (CMD+A) and copy it to your clipboard (CMD+C).
5. Confirm by pressing `return`.

---

**Teach macOS your response**

1. Open System Preferences
2. Go to Keyboard > Text
3. Press the `+` button and enter a unique shorthand (e. g. `rresponse1`). It will be replaced by your standard response.
4. Press `Tab` to go to the next field and paste your response from your clipboard (CMD+V).

[image: System Preferences > Keyboard > Text]

---

**Use your response**

1. Open your desired macOS application and click inside a text field.
2. Type your shorthand (`rresponse1`) and a `space` character.
3. macOS will expand the text for you automatically.

Does this answer your question?

[image: multi-line text replacment]

Comment: Thanks however this solution isnt perfect. I can only replace text with 1 line, not an entire email.

Comment: @Evans Please copy and paste your response. It won't work if you enter it directly in to the 'With' field.